# Salesforce Releases

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

### For a summary of [All Salesforce releases](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/whats_new.htm)

Any specific release can be accessed using the following URL

```
http://developer.force.com/releases/release/[ENTER_RELEASE_NAME_HERE]
Release name can be: summer12, winter13, etc..
```

[Spring '13](http://developer.force.com/releases/release/spring13) - [api-27](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api-27)

[Winter '13](http://developer.force.com/releases/release/winter13) - [api-26](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api-26)

[Summer '12](http://developer.force.com/releases/release/summer12) - [api-25](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api-25)

[Spring '12](http://developer.force.com/releases/release/spring12) - [api-24](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api-24)

[Winter '12](http://developer.force.com/releases/release/winter12) - [api-23](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api-23)

[Summer '11](http://developer.force.com/releases/release/summer11) - [api-22](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api-22)

[Spring '11](http://developer.force.com/releases/release/spring11) - [api-21](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api-21)

[Winter '11](http://developer.force.com/releases/release/winter11) - [api-20](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/api-20)

Comment: I was going to suggest we add synonyms for summer-12 -> api-25 etc etc but seems your already on the case :)

Comment: I guess we can do it for future releases, or every time someone tags a previous directly one.

Comment: still looking for the right format